How come AAA NiMH 750mAh batteries are charged at 15 volts?
I have an old electrical shaver which had it batteries dead. I opened it and saw that it has 2 SUPPO HSY-AAA0.75-PHP NiMH 750mAH 1316 batteries.
I am not sure what their voltage is supposed to be, but the current one is around 1.39V.
They are connected in series to the board.
The charger of the shaver says that its output is 15V. I measured the battery terminals on the board of the shaver with the charger plugged in and it is indeed 15V.
On the other hand I have a standard charger for rechargeable batteries and when I measured its output voltage for AAA slot, it shows 5V.

Can I replace the shaver batteries with normal AAA NiMH 1.2V rechargeable batteries or 15V from the shaver charge will make them explode?
How come 15V charging is OK for the current batteries of the shaver, but eventually too much (the standard battery charger is 5V) for standard AAA batteries which have the same NiMH chemistry?


measure the output of the power supply when the battery is charging

There is likely something on the board you mention that controls the charging to conform to the requirements of NiMH cells via an algorithm (perhaps with a temperature sensor to detect the typical end-of-charge sudden temperature rise). Some methods use the slight dip in cell voltage to terminate the fast charge part of the cycle.
It's not as simple as slapping a voltage source across the battery. There are ASICs that control the charging and efficiently regulate the charge current using a switching power supply. From this source:

NiMH cells are easily permanently damaged by overcharging (including trickle charge) even if they don't actually explode. The 'gas generation' (it's hydrogen, but they don't like to heavily advertise that) in the above graph is where the battery is being damaged. It's difficult to reliably terminate the charge at slow rates because both the voltage dip and the temperature dT/dt are too small to reliably detect, but the battery damage will still occur.

Hi Spehro, thank you for you answer! Do you mean that the charging is broken on the shaver, because it outputs 15V on the battery terminals? Or do you mean that it is 15V because there are no batteries currently, but when they are put, it will detect them and step down the voltage?

Hard to tell for sure, but I would suspect the latter. After all, a current source will output maximum voltage when unloaded, and 15V is way above the maximum voltage of 2 NiMH cells. Also the most likely thing we would expect to fail with age is the cells, not the circuit.

When the batteries are connected in series does the charging voltage 15V goes in half for each of them (7.5V per battery)?

@CuriousGuy If the batteries are good and almost fully charged it should drop to about 1.2V per cell, or 2.4V total. The current should be regulated.

P.S. in your case C/3 = 250mA.

Do you think that it is safe to replace the old batteries with standard AAA NiMH 750mAh 1.2V rechargeable batteries?

I'd give it a try, but watch it like a hawk (nothing flammable under or near during charging). Nothing is 100% safe, and take appropriate precautions, should you choose to do it.

The dangerous period is only during charging, right? If they charge successfully, should I worry that they can blow up in my face while shaving?

I wouldn't worry a bit. But then I visit countries that the US State Department lists as "reconsider travel".

Thank you a lot for you clarifications! I don't understand why couple of people voted -1 to my question, but your answers were really helpful to me. Thank you for your time!

NiMH cells are not charged using a voltage algorithm. They are charged via a constant current. You are measuring the open circuit voltage of the charger. When the batteries are connected, the voltage drops to around 2  to 4 volts. The trick is to know when to terminate the charge. If you are fast-charging NiMH, you must detect a voltage or temperature delta. Voltage dips slightly when the cells are fully charged—or a quick temperature rise. It takes money, circuitry, and complexity, and there is a much easier way. Consumers will not pay for a proper charger that is not needed. The competition would eat you alive.
One unique thing about NiMH batteries is that you can charge them at C/20 or less indefinitely. Some, like marketers, will call this a Trickel Charger. It is perfect for an electric razor you use once daily; it recharges between uses. It does not matter what the open circuit voltage measures; the current is what is being controlled, not the voltage. At a C/20 or less charge rate, it makes it easy, safe, and, most importantly, cheap.
